# Kendo UI Grid repeatedly passing same object to destroy command

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am working with the Kendo Grid, and I am having an issue with the destroy command button.  The button works as expected and calls the appropriate function.  The issue occurs after a second row is deleted.  On the first call the correct object is passed to the the function, on successive calls instead of sending the the object that corresponds to the row where the destroy command is pressed, it sends the object from the row of first call.  This happens for every row after the initial destroy command.  Calling the success function will cause the correct row to be removed from the grid, but as the incorrect data was passed it never gets deleted from the server(WebAPI).  I am not sure if the it is an error in the grid configuration, the datasource configuration or simply a bug. I have included the current configuration below. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
vm.gridOptions = {
      dataSource: {
        //autoSync:true, 
        schema:{
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields:{
                    id:{editable:false},
                    projectno: {editable: true},
                    description: {editable: true},
                    fund: {editable: true},
                    dept: {editable: true},
                    org: {editable: true},
                    grc: {editable: true},
                    apprunit: {editable: true},
                    objcode: {editable: true}
                }
            }
        },
        transport:{create: createProject, read: readProjects, update:saveProject, destroy: deleteProject}
      },
        selectable: false,
        sortable: true,
        editable: { mode:"popup"},
        //save:  validateProject,
        columns: [
            {
              title: "Project",
              field: "projectno",
              width: "5%"
            },
            {
              title: "Description",
              field: "description",
              width: "30%"
            },
            {
              title: "Fund",
              field: "fund",
              width: "5%"
            },
            {
              title: "Dept",
              field: "dept",
              width: "5%"
            },
            {
              title: "Org",
              field: "org",
              width: "5%"
            },
            {
              title: "GRC",
              field: "grc",
              width: "5%"
            },
            {
              title: "Appr",
              field: "apprunit",
              width: "5%"
            },
            {
              title: "Obj. Code",
              field: "objcode",
              width: "5%"
            },
            { command: "edit",width: "5%" },
            { command: "destroy",width: "5%" }
        ]
    };

 function deleteProject(options){
  projectservice.deleteProject(options.data).then(function(data){

    options.success(data)
  },function(data){
    options.error(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: What does deleteProject function contain and what does the server destroy action return in response?

Comment: I added the function at the bottom. It's a very basic function that calls a data service which is a light wrapper around an $http call.  While the the server does return a value the, issue comes before the call to the service layer.  The data object, which is a member of the options object in the call to deleteProject. already has the wrong data.  So my issue is occurring when the grid(via the datasource?) calls this method.